# How do I install a db bindings for the D programming language?

Tags: d

I tried installing several db apis in D 2.0, but the documentation is often either lacking or missing altogether.

Does someone know more on the subject?

Comment: Can you give some more information? What DB API's did you try to "install"? What did you try, and what happened when you tried to "install" them? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you have some DB library for D2 that you want to use? Can you link to the library?

Comment: D1 or D2?  For D1 you might have some luck (see Michael Minich's answer), but for D2 the core language has just stabilized recently.  Library and tool support is still very immature, though it's improving fast now that it's the main focus.

Answer (score 3):

You can find list of database bindings for D at http://www.wikiservice.at/d/wiki.cgi?DatabaseBindings. If you find more information on the net, feel free to update the page.

Many Database APIs for D are in alpha/beta, discontinued and poorly documented. It may be because many database systems provides C interface, which D can call directly - and bindings (translated C header files) are enough for many task, even if not so nice to use (for one - they may require handling of return error codes instead of exceptions).